# SQL Server Agent job runs successfully, but only for 1 second and doesn't actually do anything. Runs fine manually

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server Agent Job that runs two separate stored procedures in two steps. It's scheduled, and the scheduled run technically finishes successfully, but the run time is only 1 second and it doesn't perform the actions its supposed to. However, when I logon and run it manually, it runs fine.

Has anyone experienced this? I've debugged with TRY/CATCHes and with PRINT statements but I'm not picking up anything.

The stored procedures I'm running are a bit different that anything I've written before, as I'm building out strings to be used as statements in an EXECUTE command. Basically it just DROPs and rebuilds several tables in a loop.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @YEAR INT = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1

    WHILE (@YEAR >= 2009)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            DECLARE @TABLE_SCHEMA VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SCHEMA'
            DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(MAX) = 'BOOKSLS_' + CAST(@YEAR AS VARCHAR(4))
            DECLARE @DROP_TABLE_CMD VARCHAR(MAX) = 'DROP TABLE ' + @TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TABLE_NAME
            DECLARE @SELECT_INTO_CMD VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + @TABLE_NAME + ' FROM [LINKED_SERVER].[OTHER_SCHEMA].[BOOKSLS_' + CAST(@YEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) + ']'

            PRINT @TABLE_SCHEMA
            PRINT @TABLE_NAME
            PRINT @DROP_TABLE_CMD
            PRINT @SELECT_INTO_CMD

            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @TABLE_SCHEMA AND TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME)
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'DROP'
                EXECUTE (@DROP_TABLE_CMD)
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'INSERT'
                EXECUTE (@SELECT_INTO_CMD)
            END
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            -- Log the error to an error table
            INSERT INTO ErrorLog (ErrorMessage, ErrorTime)
            VALUES (ERROR_MESSAGE(), GETDATE())
            
            -- You can also handle the error as needed here
            -- For example, you can use RAISEERROR to re-throw the error
            -- or perform other actions.
        END CATCH

        SET @YEAR = @YEAR - 1
    END
END
```

Comment: Have you checked that table you're inserting the errors into? The reason it's successful is because you *ignore* the errors

Comment: Have you also checked the step is running in the right database?

Comment: Aside: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: SQL Agent job steps are executed in the context of a specific login. Does the login used in this job step have relevant mappings against the Linked Server object? Ref: [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedsrvlogin-transact-sql)

Comment: @ThomA So I've gone and looked at the table and it's always empty, after the scheduled runs and the manual runs. I'm also positive it's running the correct DB, as I've copied several other scheduled jobs that run fine.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have set these up in the same way as several other stored procedures on this server that access the same linked server, so I think it's got the same properties and runs under the same user.

Comment: @HABO I'll give that a shot and let you know if it works!

Comment: Copying likely hasnothing to do with being in the right database; assuming you are creating the step on the GUI then it's a drop down menu.

Comment: @ThomA It's in the right DB. I didn't actually copy it, but I made sure the owner and database were the same as ones that worked. On top of that I'm using the USE [DB]  statement in the text of the command.

Comment: To help you troubleshoot this I would add a `;throw` statement as the last statement in the catch block to allow any errors to bubble up, then execute the job and look for any error details in the SQL Agent job history

Answer (score 0):

It was a logic error with the IF/ELSE. The ELSE was not needed. So when it would run on the scheduler, it would only drop those tables, which took no time at all. When I would log in and run it after, then it would execute the ELSE block, as the tables didn't exist at that point.